# Etymology of alanine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology, amino-acids

[Oxford dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/alanine) gives etymology of [alanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanine) as:

> Coined in German as Alanin, from **al**dehyde + -**an** (for ease of pronunciation) + -**ine**.

But I see no resemblance to the aldehyde structure in alanine. Is this etymology incorrect, or am I mistaken about the resemblance?

[image: Alanine]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the original German paper [1] [Adolf Strecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolph_Strecker) used *Aldehyd-Ammoniak* or aldehyde-ammonia as a precursor, that's where the name derives from:

> Vor einigen Jahren habe ich gezeigt, daſs **Aldehyd-Ammoniak** und Blausäure beim Erwärmen mit verdünnter Chlorwasserstoffsäure sich zu einer schwachen Basis, *Alanin* genannt, vereinigen [...]:
>   $$\ce{\underset{\text{Aldehyd-Ammoniak}}{C4H4O2 * NH3} + HCl + \underset{Blausäure}{C2NH} +2 HO = \underset{Alanin}{C6H7NO4} + NH4Cl}$$

As David Richerby mentioned in the comments, Strecker's brutto-formula ($\ce{C6H7NO4}$) deviates from the moden one ($\ce{C3H7NO2}$), also the reaction scheme is a [bit different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strecker_amino_acid_synthesis).

1. Strecker, A. *Annalen der Chemie und Pharmacie* **1854**, 91 (3), 349–351. DOI [10.1002/jlac.18540910309](https://doi.org/10.1002/jlac.18540910309).

Comment: @andselisk Easy-to-understand answers to easy-to-understand questions always get lots of votes. Think of it as compensation for the times when you've spent an hour writing a detailed answer to a difficult question and it scores +2 because nobody can be bothered to read it.

Comment: Having said that, I'm a bit confused. Isn't alanine $\ce{C3H7NO2}$?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not 100% sure, but most likely it's brutto-formula was established incorrectly at that time. Many other sources around that period of time (mid 19th century) refer to alanine as to $\ce{C6H7NO4}$, or, to meet the era's spirit, $\ce{C^6H^7NO^4}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Might be worth adding a note about that to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

User364914 may be confused by the "odd" formulas in Strecker's 1854 paper. At that time there was no universal agreement on the masses of atoms. Was carbon 6 or 12? Was oxygen 8 or 16? Strecker used 6 for carbon and 8 for oxygen.

The aldehyde is acetaldehyde, $\ce{NH3}$ is OK, blausaure is hydrogen cyanide and $\ce{OH}$ is water. The corrected structures should have half the number of carbons and oxygens. The modern equation should read:

$$\ce{C2H4O.NH3 + HCl + HCN + H2O -> C3H7NO2 + NH4Cl}$$

You may want to read about the [Karlsruhe Congress of 1860](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karlsruhe_Congress).